# MetroFramework Modern UI Version 1.4.0 - TextBox & ComboBox Issue

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a **VB.NET** project with **MetroFramework Modern UI Version 1.4.0** and I have this issue... If I add a `MetroTextBox` or a `MetroComboBox` control and run it, my application goes in **Break Mode** and gives me this message `Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code).` Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Are the controls bound to anything?  Does this happen when the page with the controls open?

Comment: @KenTucker: They are placed into a `MetroTabControl` and yes, this happen only when form opens.

Comment: @KenTucker: Strange thing... If I put my `MetroTextBox` into a `MetroPanel` works fine!!!